# True or false questions for LP and the simplex method

Tags: linear-programming

> True or false?
>
> **(a)** Deleting a constraint leaves the feasible region larger.
>
> **(b)** Adding a constraint leaves the feasible region either unchanged or smaller.
>
> **(c)** An LP cannot have an unbounded objective function value.

Here are my answers:

(a) True because when I graphed a random problem, it looked like the feasible region got bigger.

(b) True -Same as (a) but saw it get smaller.

(c) True because it can have an optimal objective function value but probably not an unbounded objective function value.

But I don't understand how all three are true. Help is very much appreciated!!

Comment: What are the reasonings that lead you to those conclusions?

Comment: This should explain it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(A)$: It can also remains the same. For example for a $2$-dimensional problem, if $0 \le x\le 1$ and $0 \le y \le 1$ and $x+y \le 2$. Removing the last constraints doesn't change the feasible set.

$(B)$: Let $D$ be the initial feasible set and $D'$ be the new feasible set with more constraitns, then we have $D' \subseteq D$ since any element of $D'$ would satisfy the conditions to be in $D$.

$(C)$: Consider $\max x$, subject to $y = 0$. Is it bounded?

Comment: So (A) is false, (b) is True and (C) is false? just want to confirm

Comment: seems to be from the reasoning.

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand now.